# save new propertie asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I work with a framework where you have to extend new models, controllers.

So there is a view. And now I try to add a propertie to that existing view.

The new propertie is called:

```
public virtual string  Project_Number { get; set; }
```

and the model looks like this:

```
public class OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber: OrderOverviewModel
    {

        [Display(Name = "ProjectNumber")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLength")]
        public virtual string  Project_Number { get; set; }
        public OrderOverviewModel overViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

the view looks like this:

```
@model Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Order.OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber

<div class="additional-info">
    <h4>@Sana.SimpleText("OrderOverview_AdditionalInformation")</h4>
    @*@if (Shop.UserAbilities.Has(AbilityTo.AddReferenceNo))
    {*@
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="control">
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(it => it.ReferenceNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lbl" })
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(it => it.ReferenceNumber, new { tabindex = 1 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(it => it.ReferenceNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
    @*}*@

    @*@if (Shop.UserAbilities.Has(AbilityTo.AddReferenceNo))
    {*@
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="control">
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(it => it.Project_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lbl" })
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(it => it.Project_Number, new { tabindex = 1 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(it => it.Project_Number)
            </div>
        </div>
    @*}*@




    @if (Shop.UserAbilities.Has(AbilityTo.AddReferenceNo))
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="control">
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(it => it.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lbl" })
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(it => it.Comments, new { tabindex = 1 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(it => it.Comments)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (Shop.UserAbilities.Has(AbilityTo.AddRequestedDeliveryDate))
    {
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="control">
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(it => it.DeliveryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lbl" })
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(it => it.DeliveryDate, new { tabindex = 1 })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(it => it.DeliveryDate)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

But I have some problems with the Controller. The controller looks like this:

```
 public class ExtendedOrderManager : OrderManager<IExtendedOrderProvider>
    {
        public string CustomAction(int value)
        {
            var cacheKey = CacheKey.ForErpItem<object>("customaction_" + value, cacheGroup: "abc");
            return CacheManager.FromCache(cacheKey, () => Provider.CustomAction(value));
        }

        public override IOrder SaveOrder(IOrder order)
        {
            //order.Fields.SetField(new Entities.EntityField("BlanketOrderId", "BO1") { StoreWithEntity = true });

            //order["BlanketOrderId"] = "BO1";
            //order.Fields["BlanketOrderId"].StoreWithEntity = true;

            return base.SaveOrder(order);
        }
    }
```

IOrder looks like this:

```
 //
    // Summary:
    //     This interface represents an order in the ERP system. This can be an order that
    //     still has to be placed or an order that is already in the ERP (for example order
    //     history). There are several types of orders like regular orders, invoice and
    //     quotes. The type of order is stored in the document type property.
    public interface IOrder : IEntity, IVersionedItem
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the account that placed the order.
        string AccountId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The type of account that placed this order.
        AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the list of order attachments.
        IList<IAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the status of order authorization.
        OrderAuthorizationStatus AuthorizationStatus { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Address that will recieve the invoice.
        ICustomerAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets bill-to name.
        string BillToName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the comment.
        string Comment { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the Contact that placed this order.
        string Contact { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the Contact that placed this order.
        string ContactId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the currency used to place this order (for example USD). This can be different
        //     from the current users default currency.
        string CurrencyId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total amount of discount the customer gets over this order. This includes
        //     linediscount over all basketlines and invoice discount.
        decimal DiscountAmount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Document date.
        Date? DocumentDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The OrderId (in the case of other types than Order or Quote).
        string DocumentId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the document type.
        string DocumentType { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Due date.
        Date? DueDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the value indicating whether this order has report.
        bool HasReport { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The ID of the instance.
        string Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total amount of invoice discount the customer gets over his/her order. This
        //     is calculated using the totalprice without VAT.
        decimal InvoiceDiscount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this quote is confirmed.
        bool IsQuoteConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Location code.
        string LocationCode { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the max expired date.
        DateTime? MaxExpirationDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Date on which the order was placed.
        Date OrderDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The order lines.
        IList<IOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The number of order lines.
        int OrderLinesCount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the order type.
        OrderType? OrderType { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The ID of the sales order which this document is linked to. For example, if it
        //     is an 'Invoice' document then this field should be the ID of the sales order
        //     for which this invoice has been posted. In case this is an 'Order' or 'Quote'
        //     document type then this field should be empty.
        string OriginalOrderId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the original quote identifier.
        string OriginalQuoteId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total amount outstanding.
        decimal OutstandingAmount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Address of the company the order was paid by.
        ICustomerAddress PayerAddress { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Payment Discount.
        decimal PaymentDiscount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Payment Discount Date.
        Date? PaymentDiscountDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the payment method used by the customer.
        string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Status of the Payment of this order.
        string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Payment terms code.
        string PaymentTermsCode { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The payment transaction ID.
        string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Posting Date.
        Date? PostingDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the prepayment amount.
        decimal PrepaymentAmount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the prepayment percentage.
        decimal PrepaymentPercentage { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether prices include tax.
        bool PricesInclTax { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Promised Delivery Date.
        Date? PromisedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the reference no.
        string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Requested Delivery Date.
        Date? RequestedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The round-off value, which is added or substracted from the subtotal value when
        //     the rounding precision of total costs is corrected on the ERP side.
        decimal RoundOff { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the sales person that placed this order.
        string SalesPerson { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     ID of the sales person that placed this order.
        string SalesPersonId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the Sana internal order identifier.
        string SanaOrderId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Address of the company the order was selled to.
        ICustomerAddress SellToAddress { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Date the order was shipped.
        Date? ShipmentDate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Address this order will or was shipped to.
        ICustomerAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Code (string) of the method the order was shipped by.
        string ShippingMethodCode { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the method the order was shipped by.
        string ShippingMethodName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the shipping status. Order is shipped only if order lines are shipped.
        string ShippingStatus { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The shipping tracking link provided by the shipping agent.
        string ShippingTrackingLink { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The shipping tracking number provided by the shipping agent.
        string ShippingTrackingNumber { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets ship-to name.
        string ShipToName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the e-mail address of the shop account who placed this order.
        string ShopAccountEmail { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the status of this order.
        OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total Amount of tax the user has to pay over all basket lines.
        decimal TaxAmount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The lines containing taxes.
        IList<ITaxLine> TaxLines { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The percentage of tax that is used for this order (for example when tax is 19%,
        //     this property contains 19).
        decimal TaxPercent { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total price of all products of this order including invoice discount and
        //     VAT.
        decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total price of all products of this order without any discounts or tax added.
        decimal TotalPriceExcludingDiscount { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The total price of all products of this order including invoice discount, but
        //     excluding tax.
        decimal TotalPriceExcludingTax { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The Total number of products this order contains.
        decimal TotalQuantity { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The ID of the website.
        string WebsiteId { get; set; }
    }
```

But this is a DLL. So I cant add new properties to the IOrder class.

Because if I put a breakpoint on the Controller method: SaveOrder

and I watch the properties in the order IOrder order. I see that projectnumber is null.

So my question is: How to manage that the projectnumber gets a value?

Thank you

And this is the order class:

```
[Serializable]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Order : Entity, IOrder
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Status of the Payment of this order.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }



        [DataMember]
        [XmlField]
        public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The address the customer should recieve the bill.
}
```

So I have added a new Inteface like this:

```
 interface IOrderProjectNumber:IOrder
    {
        string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

If I look in the method: SaveOrder(Iorder order) and I hover my mouse on the order I see the propertie ProjectNumber is null

But if I look in the immediate Window And If I do this: ?order.proje... I dont see a propertie projectNumber?? How can that be?

Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBlZt.png)

Comment: Please post relevant code only. Others may get confused. And also explain your problem clearly.

Comment: First in SaveOrder create one variable and cast Order to OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber. Check if you are getting value. Also, while saving after base.save you need to put additional logic to save projectnumber. Same is the case while fetching.

Answer (score 1):

I will separate your question to 2 parts:

1) How to get `Project_Number` from View

2) How to save `Project_Number` to database

For question 1)

- You need to check your `Select`. How do you display `OrderoverviewModel_ProjectNumber`? You might need to add `Project_Number` inside that `Select` function
- In Edit View, you doesn't read/edit `Project_Number` so in-fact, it's null.
  In case you don't want to change `Project_Number`, then check back the first point,you might miss getting this from database.

For question 2)

- A tricky part here, as you might not have the source code for `IOrder`. However, it's an interface, so you can check the whole solution again, may be the main class is `Order`?
- In case you can't find it, i suggest to rewrite the code part, as you should not store the `Project_Number` differently with other properties

Update-1: Now, let add the `Project_Number` to `IOrder.cs`. Added it in `Order.cs` if it needed too.
Finally, to store it in database, check the method `SaveOrder(IOrder order)` in `OrderManager`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For question 1. I already get the propertie it.Project_Number, from view. So that is not the problem.

Comment: HI, I made an update. I have added the Order class with the new propertie  public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, but I cant modify the Interface IOrder.cs. because it is a dll

Comment: Ok. I modified the post.

Comment: Somebody any ideer? Thank you